# Are planar 2nd order NURBS curve segments exactly the segments of conic sections?

Tags: interpolation, b-spline

I think it is well known that 2nd order NURBS curve can describe any segment of a conic section. Such a segment has 7 degrees of freedom, take an ellipse arc for example: the ellipse itself has 5 degrees of freedom (center, half-axes and rotation), and the two points on the ellipse (2 angles) give the remaining 2 degrees of freedom. A 2nd order NURBS curve segment has less than 9 degrees of freedom: 3 control points and 3 weights, but the scaling of the weights is irrelevant. Can one discuss away the remaining additional degree of freedom?

(I think I can show that a planar 2nd order B-SPLINE segment is a segment of a parabola or of a line. The argument that both have 6 degrees of freedoms applies, but the algebra is also easy to work out.)